# Árbol de búsqueda binaria

Tags: javascript, recursión

Estoy creando una clase para un árbol binario de búsqueda, estoy iniciando a conocer javascript y no tiendo por que esto no esta funcionando, cree el metodo inOrder solo para ver que todo se este insertando correctamente, pero no funciona.

- BST y Nodo

```
class Node {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
class BST {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
        this.nodes = 0;
    }
    push(data, root = this.root) {
        if (!root) {
            root = new Node(data);
            this.nodes++;
        }
        else {
            if (data > root.data) this.push(data,root.right);
            else this.push(data,root.left);
        }
    }
    inOrder(root = this.root) {
        if (root) {
            this.inOrder(root.left);
            console.log(root.data);
            this.inOrder(root.right);
        }
    }
}
```

- Ejecución

```
function main() {
    let tree = new BST();

    for (let i = 1; i<11; i++) {
        tree.push(i);
    }

    tree.inOrder();
}
main()
```

Comment: Nunca es bueno iniciar algo como `null` ya que si de casualidad haces una operacion matematica con un `null` el resultado va a ser un `NaN`, de todas maneras no he visto bien el codigo, pero dejare esta informacion por aqui por si acaso.

Comment: Creo que a la implementación de tu BST le hace falta ampliar el método push, ya que la forma en la que has planteado la recursión del `push(data, root)` no crea en ningún momento un nuevo nodo para el valor/data que vas a insertar después de llegar a su posición correcta, ya que la creación del nodo en el if tampoco parece ser correcta, pues que te faltaría hacer el linkado desde el nodo padre (algo tipo `this.right = newCreatedNode` por ejemplo).

Comment: @Sema ha funcionado, crei que Javascript podría funcionar como C++ donde en la dirección de memoria, unque sea un null, puede crearse un nodo, pero parece ser que no, gracais : )

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido! :)